# Get collection of items from c# function composite c1

Tags: c#, c1-cms

I wrote a C# function that retries a list of users from Active Directory.

```
        public static IEnumerable<string> ActiveDirectoryUsersList()
        {
            string[] adPropertiesToRetrive = { "displayName", "mail", "telephoneNumber", "displayName", "mobile" };
            List<string> usersInfo = new List<string>();
            // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  
            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=OUName,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
            foreach (var prop in adPropertiesToRetrive)
            {
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(prop);
            }

            SearchResultCollection allUsers = search.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult user in allUsers)
            {
                foreach (var prop in adPropertiesToRetrive)
                {
                    var val = user.Properties[prop].Count > 0 ? user.Properties[prop][0].ToString() : "-";
                    usersInfo.Add(val);

                }

            }
            return usersInfo;
        }
```

now I want to use this in my Razor function and iterate something like this:

```
@foreach (var user in Fucntion("Custom.ActiveDirectoryUsersList"))
{
    @user
}
```

but the result of Function(string Name) is an HTML string result.
How can i call upon the inline C# function defined to get the raw result of the function?

Comment: Explicit call of [Namespace].[Class].ActiveDirectoryUsersList() does not work?

Comment: Nope getting a missing assembly reference, you are aware that we are talking about Composite C1 right ?

Comment: My bad, missed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var user in Function("Custom.ActiveDirectoryUsersList"))
{
   <text>@Html.Raw(user)</text>
}
```

could do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

The Function-method in a Razor Page is designed for outputting Html so that's why its behaving the way it is. If you want to retrieve any non-html value from your function, you can use the `Functions.ExecuteFunction(...)` helper method, which returns an `object` which you can then cast to the type you know your function is returning.

So all in all would your code look like this

```
@foreach (var user in ((IEnumerable<string>)Functions.ExecuteFunction("Custom.ActiveDirectoryUsersList")))
{
  <span>@user</span>
}
```

Or a bit cleaner

```
@{
  var users = (IEnumerable<string>)Functions.ExecuteFunction("Custom.ActiveDirectoryUsersList");

  foreach (var user in users)
  {
    <span>@user</span>
  }
}
```

[Read about the Functions helper class here](https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/blob/dev/Composite/AspNet/Razor/Functions.cs)